# How can I get a square wave by using python pandas or matplotlib？

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I’m trying to use python to deal with data to get a SPC or CPK chart.
I want to draw a line like ‘UCL’ as below. But now, I can only draw a line like P-bar.
How can I get it in an easy way？

[image]

my code：

```
df.plot(x=‘StartDateTime’,y=[‘UCL’,’LCL’,’P-bar’,’P’])
plt.show()
```

And I get this:
[image]

Comment: How about you show what you actually did and explain why it doesn't work. Having requirements is nice, but SO is not a free coding site.

Comment: Do you want both the UCL and LCL lines to be square?

Comment: @DavidG Yes! I want both of them to be square

Comment: @MadPhysicist I’m so sorry that I use my phone to ask this question and it is hard to share my data...

Answer (score 2):

One option is to simply set the linestyle of the plots to be "steps" using the `linestyle=` argument of `df.plot()`:

```
df.plot(x='StartDateTime', y=['UCL','LCL','P-bar','P'], linestyle='steps')
```

Comment: Yes，It's exactly what I want！